# can't get my php to work for a contact form

Tags: php

I made my contact form on a contact.html page and in form I put action="mail.php" and then I made a mail.php page. once I put all my php in the page my send button wouldn't work. and yes I have tried making my contact.html page contact.php but my website won't open that link up at all. I'm using atom.
need help. asking for a friend.

I need the right php for the contact form so I can be able to get an email when someone submits a form.

Here is my Contact.html page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ITA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<header>

<div class="container">

<img src="../pics/LogoMakr_89l9j5.png" alt="logo" class="logo">

<nav>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

 </div>


 </header>

<form action="mail.php" method="post">

  <body class="contactbgimg">

<div class="contact-form">
  <h1>Contact Us</h1>

<div class="txtb">
  <label>Full Name :</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
</div>

<div class="txtb">
  <label>Email :</label>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required>
</div>

<div class="txtb">
  <label>Phone Number :</label>
  <input placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number" required>
</div>

<div class="txtb">
  <label>Message:</label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Text" required>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Send" name="Submit">

</form>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please make sure to show us what you have so far. Show us the contact.html and mail.php page. Tell us what you've tried so far. We cannot help you with the amount of information you have given us. And. Is PHP working or not?

Comment: I can't put a picture because stack overflow won't let me

Comment: No need for pictures, just post all relevant code and information we need to know in your post.

Comment: Hi there. Please post your HTML so we can help you out easier

Comment: I posted the html file

Comment: <div class="contact-form">   in your form is not closed.I guess that it's the issue which cause you error  .

Comment: You need to go and learn what the basic structure of an HTML document is. You have a `body` nested inside a `form`, which is so massively wrong to begin with, that the rest of it does not even warrant further inspection at this point.

Comment: When I hit submit, all the php shows up in the website

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

1) contact.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ITA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<header>

<div class="container">
<img src="../pics/LogoMakr_89l9j5.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</header>
<body class="contactbgimg">
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
<div class="contact-form">
<h1>Contact Us</h1>

    <div class="txtb">
        <label>Full Name :</label>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="txtb">
        <label>Email :</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required>
    </div>

    <div class="txtb">
        <label>Phone Number :</label>
        <input type="text" name="contactno" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number" required>
    </div>

    <div class="txtb">
        <label>Message:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Text" required>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>

    <input class="btn" type="submit" name="Submit">
</div>
</form>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

2) mail.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $contactno = $_POST['contactno'];
    //All your Business logic goes here.

    echo "Name : ".$fullname."<br>Email ID :".$email."<br>Contact # :".$contactno;
}

?>
```